# Hadoop Text is mutable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am unable to understand the logic for his piece of code:

```
    Text text = new Text("hadoop");
    System.out.println(text.getLength());
    System.out.println(text.getBytes().length);
    text.set(new Text("pig"));
    System.out.println(text.getLength());
    System.out.println(text.getBytes().length);
```

Why is the last print statement gives `6` and not `3`? Please explain - totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is backed by a byte array to hold its actual value. When the value of Text is updated, the content of the byte array is overwritten instead of replacing the whole byte array object, if the new value fits into the current byte array (otherwise a new byte array is created).
In your example, you initialize Text with the value "hadoop" which requires a byte array of length 6. When you set the new value to "pig", "pig" is copied into the existing byte array of length 6, i.e., Text does NOT create a new byte array of length 3 for that. I assume, byte arrays are reused to reduce the number of object instantiations and reduce pressure on the garbage collector.

The JavaDocs for the Text.getBytes() says:

> Returns the raw bytes; however, only data up to getLength() is valid. Please use copyBytes() if you need the returned array to be precisely the length of the data.